# Is it required to keep a Form W-8BEN when paying a foreign contractor?

Tags: united-states, international, contractor, form-w-8-ben

Bob is a French citizen is a tax resident and permanent resident of the United States. Alice is not a U.S. person and works only  outside the U.S.

If Bob pays Alice for some work she performed, is it required for Bob to keep a Form W-8BEN (which Alice would complete and give to Bob)?

---

I'm reading conflicting information. https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/2428027-do-i-have-to-prepare-a-1099-misc-for-a-foreign-contractor-who-performed-services-related-to-a-foreign-rental-property ([mirror](http://archive.is/6eqxw)) seems to say that the W-8BEN is optional:

> As long as the foreign contractor is not a U.S. person and the services are wholly performed outside the U.S., then no Form 1099 is required and no withholding is required.
>
> However (Treas. Reg. §1.1441-1(b)(3)), **it is generally easier to  ask them to complete a Form W-8BEN**.  By signing Form W-8BEN, the foreign contractor is certifying that he or she is not a U.S. person.
>
> The Form W-8BEN is not filed with the I.R.S.  It is kept on file with the U.S. payor in case the U.S. payor is audited.  If audited, the Form W-8BEN supports why no Form 1099 was issued and why no tax was withheld.

(my understanding of this quote is that the form W-8BEN can be used for the audit but it is not required and other types of evidence could be provided.)

whereas https://www.kahnlitwin.com/news/articles/Reporting-U.S.-Business-Payments-To-Foreign-Individuals-for-Services-Perfor ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170108145859/http://www.kahnlitwin.com/news/articles/Reporting-U.S.-Business-Payments-To-Foreign-Individuals-for-Services-Perfor)) says:

> Form W-8 is not required to be filed with the IRS but **is required to be kept by the U.S. payor** to support the foreign contractor’s representation of their residency and whether withholding was required. Note this documentation is crucial to have in case your company is audited by IRS.